# how to make it work bootstrap form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

contact.php

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contactproces.php" class="closeForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-template">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

contactproces.php

```
 <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent=" From: $name \n  Email: $email \n  Subject: $subject  \n  
    Message: $message";
    $recipient = "admin@...com";
    $subject = "Enquiry Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank you for getting in touch..! We will get back you as soon as we review your message.";
 ?>
```

This is my bootstrap contact form code which is simple  and works fine but when i try to use it for wordpress am getting error i tried many things by changing action field .can anyone tell me what real modification i have to do with this contactfrm so this works fine in wordpress.pleasse share the solution

Error:
i dont know what possible changes i have to make and how to link those pages in php and where to place the php code.i tried placing contactprocess code in cotact.php before get_header(); and in action i added (action="php the_permalink(); ") . in that its displaying message at the top (Thank you for getting in touch..! We will get back you as soon as we review your message.) without submitting form.and when i try to submit the form it direct to the same link which is domianname/contact/ with home page content and getting mail without content

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: for now this is in bootstrap . i dont  know what possible chnages i have to make and how to link those pages i php and where to place the php code.i tried placing contactprocess code in cotact.php before <?php get_header(); ?> and in action i added  (action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>") this in that its dislaying essage at the top (Thank you for getting in touch..! We will get back you as soon as we review your message.) without submitting form.and when i try to submit the form i direct to the same link which is domianname/contact/ with home page content and getting mail without content

Comment: is there anyone who can help me

Comment: You can process the form via Ajax. Put the process script inside your theme folder, and call the script via the resource (http: site /wp-content /themes /mytheme /script. Php)

Comment: script contains contactprocess.php code right and in contact.php ACTION="http: site /wp-content /themes /mytheme /script. Php".iS THIS  THE WAY?

Comment: your trick worked for me but is there any solution to call it dynamically

Comment: Yes using Ajax. Maybe with jquery. Read about: send form with Ajax jquery php